# Why does my tkinter app will show a node.js window?

Tags: python, node.js, tkinter, python-requests, pyinstaller

I use `pyinstaller` to pack a .py file.

Then when I use something about web crawler (I use requests module).

This window will show and disappear fastly.

I want to say that it is maybe incredible.It wouldn't pop this window when I run this `.py` file,but after using `pyinstaller` to pack it,it will pop this window.

(In another computer,it doesn't install `node.js`.And it doesn't pop this window)

Here is the module I use:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import ctypes
from io import BytesIO
import threading
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import base64
from win32com.shell import shell
import requests
import execjs
import sys
import pythoncom
import getpass
import tkinter
from random import randint
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import json
import traceback
from webbrowser import open_new_tab
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import win32con, win32clipboard, win32gui
from PIL.ImageGrab import grabclipboard, grab
from aip import AipOcr
import time
```

And the window is this:
[image]

What should I do except uninstall `node.js`? How to avoid this `node.js` window shows?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you have imported `execjs` module, so your code may execute some JavaScript using the module function.  The module may try to pick one of the engine installed to execute the JavaScript and this time it chooses `node.js`.  So you should look into `execjs` document how to choose the engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks bro,acw1668's suggestion enlighten me a lot.

I want to say,`execjs` module will run js code.
And if your computer install `node.js` and you set PATH for `node.js`,Then your default js environment is `node.js`(If you don't install `node.js`,then your default js environment is `Jscript` in windows system).

So if you doesn't want to use `node.js`,you should set the default js environment in python.

```
# change the js environment.
os.environ["EXECJS_RUNTIME"] = "JScript"

# all of environment which execjs support
  PyV8           = "PyV8"
  Node           = "Node"
  JavaScriptCore = "JavaScriptCore"
  SpiderMonkey   = "SpiderMonkey"
  JScript        = "JScript"
  PhantomJS      = "PhantomJS"
  SlimerJS       = "SlimerJS"
  Nashorn        = "Nashorn"
```

Comment: But after you use pyinstaller to pack it,if you don't use console(``-w``),then it won't call javascript code.