# Close the cmd window after using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Firstly,I know that `-w` is no-console when I use pyinstaller.

Due to some reasons,I have to use console.Is it possible to close the CMD window(without exiting this exe file) and can show it again when I need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't. If you want to have a window like that, you'll have to write a custom shell window using wxPython or PyQt5.

Comment: Ok,thanks.I will try to do this with using tkinter.

Comment: Oh,I want to say that ``pyinstaller`` maybe has conflict with ``execjs`` module.When I use ``os.environ["EXECJS_RUNTIME"] = "JScript"`` to set the javascript environment in python,it won't run this code if I use pyinstaller with ``-w``.(Now this .exe file has console window and can run normally.)

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA you'll need a piece of code called a runtime hook to fix this probably. They're quite complex - the docs don't actually have anything on them specifically because the devs (me included) don't want people messing with them. They are the part most likely to break another computer when you run your program.

Comment: Okay,I don't set javascript environment in python.But the exe file will always show node.js window.(likes this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60351780/why-does-my-tkinter-app-will-show-a-node-js-window)) ,It won't happen when I run this code in IDE.But after I use pyinstaller to pack it,it will show node.js window when I run this exe file.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help with that; not my area.

Comment: You'll need to figure out what is causing it though :-) and track it down.